# Initialization error when using tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn with sequence_length

Tags: python, tensorflow

The code below works fine:

```
with tf.variable_scope("lstm"):
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=512)
    outputs, final_state = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(
            cell=cell,
            inputs=x,
            dtype=tf.int32)
```

However, when I give it `sequence_length`, it complains:

```
ValueError: Initializer for variable lstm/rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel/ is from inside a control-flow construct, such as a loop or conditional. When creating a variable inside a loop or conditional, use a lambda as the initializer.
```

I have read in the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/static_rnn) that "if the `sequence_length` vector is provided, dynamic calculation is performed." I was wondering why it has anything to do with "loop or conditional" and how should I fix this problem. Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Here is the code that breaks:

```
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, sentence_len, feature_len])
x_unstacked = tf.unstack(x, sentence_len, 1)
xlen = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None])

with tf.variable_scope("lstm"):
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=512)
    outputs, final_state = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(
            cell=cell,
            inputs=x_unstacked,
            dtype=tf.int32,
            sequence_length=xlen)
```

Comment: please show your code for the case with the sequence_size definition and include initialization of parameters.

Comment: @asakryukin Hi! I included the code. However I didn't do any initialization manually.

Comment: it runs without any error for me, are you sure it's not running inside any external loop or if()?

Comment: @asakryukin After pasting the code to another file, it works fine for me. I will try to find out what the problem was and post as soon as possible. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @asakryukin After changing `dtype` back to `int32`, the problem is back... This is probably a bug in Tensorflow?

Comment: what tensorflow version are you using? I was having a similar issue now. Rolling back from tensorflow==1.3.0 to tensorflow==1.1.0 fixed it (with Keras==2.1.1).

Comment: @shadi `pip freeze` gives me `tensorflow==1.3.0rc0
tensorflow-gpu==1.4.0
tensorflow-tensorboard==0.4.0rc2
`. I suppose the erroneous version is 1.4.0 because I noticed my GPU was used during the execution.